# Splitting students into groups to work with different students

Tags: python, oop, project

I have to make a program (not GUI) that can split approximately 25 students into small groups consisting of only 3-4 members. Every time I split the groups, students have to pair with different students that they have least worked with.

For example, if I have students like s1, s2, s3, s4... Let's say in the first sessions we have s1, s2, s3 as a group and in the second session, we have s2,s3,s4 as a group. When it comes to the third session, s2 cannot be grouped with s3 because they had that student in their previous 2 sessions.

The idea behind the program is to make students work with different students as much as possible. If we have an index/dictionary or something for each student to know the number of times they have worked with other students. Then the grouping criteria should be grouping them with 2-3 students who they met the least number of times.

I don't know whether this is possible without algorithms.

I'd like to know your suggestions and thoughts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A special case of your question would be what is known as a *social square*: we have `N` groups of `N` students, and we want each student to work exactly once with any other. In your example, 5 groups of 5 students each, and since each student must meet 24 others, and meets them 4 at a time we will have `24/4=6`, i.e. `N+1` sessions.

There are a few known algorithms for solving that, but unfortunately they work only when `N` is prime. When `N` isn't prime a solution still exists, but afaik you need to brute force it. However since you're allowing some repetitions you may probably use a variation of the standard algo to get what you need.

One algorithm is as follows:

- put the students in a `NxN` matrix
- for the first session, each row is one group
- for the following sessions, take a student from each row. First time you take them vertically, then you shift by one column per row, then by two (circularly): so at the second session the first group is `Row1Col1`, `Row2Col1`, ..., `Row5Col1`; at the third session the first group is `Row1Col1`, `Row2Col2`, ..., `Row5Col5`; note the fourth session: `Row1Col1`, `Row2Col3`, `Row3Col5`, *`Row4Col2`*, `Row5Col4`; and so on

Here is a sample implementation:

```
def social_square(no_students):
    roster = [[f'S{row}{col}' for col in range(no_students)] for row in range(no_students)]
    sessions = []
    #1st
    sessions.append([[roster[row][col] for col in range(no_students)] for row in range(no_students)])
    #following
    for delta in range(no_students):
        session = []
        for step in range(no_students):
            group = []
            col = step
            for row in range(no_students):
                group.append(roster[row][col])
                col = (col + delta) % no_students
            session.append(group)
        sessions.append(session)

    for session in sessions:
        for group in session:
            print(group)
        print()
```

Comment: What if there are an odd number of students where you can't form a matrix ?(like 21/22)

Comment: The usual trick is to add "dummy" students to do the computation and then remove them from the group listing - some groups will have less than `N` students of course

Comment: But as I said, the social square is a _special_ case, and it's just an example of how to deal with this class of problems. Your original requirement is something that we may call a "social rectangle with repetitions allowed"

Comment: yes. Repetitions allowed.